# Raising a custom fault in Apigee

Tags: exception, apigee

I want to raise a fault in apigee edge while validation an apikey. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<GetOAuthV1Info enabled="true" continueOnError="false" async="false" name="ValidateAPIKey">
    <DisplayName>Validate API Key Policy</DisplayName>

    <FaultRules>
      <FaultRule>
        <Description>InvalidApiKey</Description>
        <Condition>(flow.param.apikey)=NULL</Condition>
      </FaultRule>

    </FaultRules>

    <Properties/>
    <AppKey ref="flow.param.apikey"/>
</GetOAuthV1Info>
```

Comment: You should use the [`VerifyApiKey`](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/enforce-access-control-using-verifyapikey) policy to verify API keys, rather than that `GetOAuthV1Info` thing.

Answer (score 2):

The [`VerifyApiKey`](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/enforce-access-control-using-verifyapikey) policy  (or the GetOAuthV1Info policy) itself will raise a fault if the key is null or not passed.  There is no need to call `RaiseFault` explicitly.

The typical VerifyApiKey usage is like this:

```
<VerifyAPIKey enabled='true' name='VerifyKey-1'>
  <DisplayName>Verify API Key</DisplayName>
  <APIKey ref='request.queryparam.apikey'></APIKey>
</VerifyAPIKey>
```

If you want to do a pre-emptive check for the presence of an apikey, before running that policy, then you could add a flow step like this

```
<Request>
  <Step>
    <Condition>(request.queryparam.key=null) or (request.queryparam.key=EMPTY)</Condition>
    <Name>RaiseFault-key_not_found</Name>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <Name>VerifyKey-1</Name>
  </Step>
</Request>
```

`RaiseFault-key_not_found` is a [`RaiseFault`](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/exception-handling-raisefault) policy, like below:

```
<RaiseFault name="RaiseFault-key_not_found">
  <FaultResponse>
    <Set>
      <Payload contentType="application/xml">
        <consumer>
          <error>
            <message>Key doesn't Exists</message>
          </error>
        </consumer>
      </Payload>
    </Set>
  </FaultResponse>
</RaiseFault>
```

And of course that payload could be JSON or plaintext or something else if you prefer.

Comment: this sort of worked for me...except I wanted to use dynamic content on the RaiseFault policy as seen [here](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/exception-handling-raisefault) I would get an HTTP 500 error whenever I use {} notation to insert dynamic content from apigee variables like {response.status.code}..if i don't use them it works as explained above

Comment: My answer shows use of fault policy in <Request> flow, if you want to use the example in documentation, place the fault policy in <Response> flow since it use a response variable.

Comment: I'm using the RaiseFault policy on the Verify API Key policy, which is in the RequestFlow

Comment: Yes Dexter, thats is the problem.response object is not created yet during the request flow. So you should generate a new response object. Can you tell me the response you want your users to see when verify API Key fails? I can give you a fault policy that generates that response.

Comment: not sure i follow...but in any case, what i'm trying to do is the one in your [online documentation](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/exception-handling-raisefault#sample-raisefault-policy).  I followed that to create a dynamic payload and it throws an http 500.  I also tried one of the `fault.*` variables and that doesn't work, either (throws http 500).  perhaps it's better to modify the online doc to show what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I believe handling Faults for policies has been changed a bit now. But has not been reflected properly in the policy schema's or in the [Apigee docs](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/fault-handling)

Defining Fault rules within the policy/step definition is not working now.
You will have to define Fault rules as a flow like pre flow or post flow and include your fault definitions within it. Like shown below..

```
<ProxyEndpoint name="default"> 
<Description/> 
<FaultRules> 
<FaultRule name="InvalidApiKeyXml"> 
<Condition>fault.name == &quot;InvalidApiKey&quot;</Condition> 
<Step> 
<Name>invalidAccessForXML</Name> <!-- step to call on fault could be a raise fault or assignmessage policy --> 
</Step> 
</FaultRule> 
</FaultRules>
... 
</Flows> 
... 
</ProxyEndpoint>
```

And Not within the policy like your usage:

    Validate API Key Policy

```
<FaultRules>
  <FaultRule>
    <Description>InvalidApiKey</Description>
    <Condition>(flow.param.apikey)=NULL</Condition>
  </FaultRule>

</FaultRules>

<Properties/>
<AppKey ref="flow.param.apikey"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fault rule would look like this

```
 <FaultRule>
    <Name>InvalidApiKey</Description>
    <Condition>(fault.name = oauth.v2.InvalidApiKey)</Condition>
</FaultRule>
```

The Name element references a policy, usually an AssignMessage policy, that creates the response message for the error condition.

The Condition element defines the condition that will fire the policy. Each policy defines a list of error codes that you can use as fault.name variables.

You can read more about fault handling here:

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/fault-handling

Comment: I am not sure what I was doing wrong , In my policy I was looking to fire the policy if the apikey is null . Even when I do not add the API key to the param it still does not execute this fault though .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the fault for a missing API Key, that error code is this:

{"errorcode":"steps.oauth.v2.FailedToResolveAPIKey"}

You may want to play around with the API key sample to while you get the hang of it:

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/apikey

Comment: Best to edit your existing answer rather than leaving a new one ;)